# No color showing in phpunit tests

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit

I'm using Symfony2 and under app/phpunit.xml.dist

I have the color option turned on.

```
<phpunit
    ...
    colors = "true"
    ...
```

I'm using ssh under Ubuntu 14.04 and using PHPUnit 4.1.1.

I execute my tests via a bin included in Symfony2.

```
bin/phpunit src/Acme/Bundle/Tests
```

The only thing I found on the net was to get the colors to turn off but not troubleshooting to get them on.

Is there anything else I need to do to get the colors to display?

Comment: Could you add to your question how do you execute `phpunit` ?

Comment: Maybe it's not getting the correct configuration. Try adding the `--configuration [PATH_]/app/phpunit.xml.dist` option to the phpunit execution.   (Example: `bin/phpunit --configuration /home/Tek/workspace/app/phpunit.xml.dist src/Acme/Bundle/Tests` )

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. `bin/phpunit -c app/ sometestdir` did it. :) Add as an answer?

Comment: hehe nice! I'm glad that I indirectly helped you. I think you should add this as an answer because you found it :)

Comment: Wouldn't have found it without you! Go ahead, I insist. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `phpunit` it is not getting the correct configuration.

From the [Symfony documentation:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html)

```
The -c option tells PHPUnit to look in the app/ directory for a configuration file. If you're curious about the PHPUnit options, check out the app/phpunit.xml.dist file.
```

And, as you correctly found it, the usage is the following:

`bin/phpunit -c app/ sometestdir`

With this you are telling `phpunit` to grab the configuration from the `app/` directory and then test the `sometestdir` folder.

:)

More info at http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions